# Sending email as an alias in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have an Outlook server with 1 email address. (**office@domain.com**) I want three users to have aliases for that email: **alice@domain.com**, **bob@domain.com**, and **carol@domain.com**.

I want all three aliases to be active. For instance, say Alice receives an email. It would go to **office@domain.com** and be labeled for Alice. (I can do auto labeling without difficulty.)

However, when she replies to the person who wrote her, I'd like them to see her email as **alice@domain.com**, not **office@domain.com**.

Is this functionality available directly in Outlook settings? I am currently using both Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.

Comment: Do the other accounts exist?

Comment: You should be able to do this when you setup the account on the machine itself.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Outlook specifically, but wouldn't the easiest way for this be to add the office inbox to alice, bob and carols clients? They will have two separate inboxes, but that might be a good thing, and when they reply from the shared inbox I'm pretty sure it will show up as being sent from the e-mail that the shared inbox belongs to